# ML .NET Image Classification - Can i predict an image using byte array instead of file path on default MLNET training?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, computer-vision, ml.net

I have trained a model using MLNET default interface, and it generated some code for input and output of the prediction.

[image]

At all, my model is fine, it is predicting at a good score, but i'm having problems on prediction performance because of the need to have the file saved on disk for prediction.

```
public class ModelInput
{
    [ColumnName("Label"), LoadColumn(0)]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [ColumnName("ImageSource"), LoadColumn(1)]
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

this is the default model input it generates. i checked the schema on the loaded model, and i can see there is a "Features" column that is a byte vector, and tried to add it on my input, but it is not considered when doing the prediction.

I have coded another training by my own, trying to generate a new model that uses byte vector as input by default, but the training is freezing my PC, i have tested it in a friend's PC and it worked, with this new model i can predict with byte vector, but i cant use my friend's PC everytime i need to retrain the model.

Can anyone help me ? Is there a way to predict the default model with vector byte?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the responses in this issue might be able to help you achieve the expected result.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder/issues/851